# NGINX Amazon EC2 keeps loading but shows nothing

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2

I'm kinda new on setting up a production machine and I don't get why I'm not seeing the default index page for nginx on my EC2 machine. It's installed and running on my server, but when I try to access, it keeps loading and shows nothing, keeps on a blank page. I'm trying to access through the public ip (35.160.22.104) and through public dns(ec2-35-160-22-104.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com). Both does the same. What I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE:
I realized that when restarting nginx service, it didn't showed the "ok" message. So I took a look at error.log:

```
[ 2016-12-12 17:16:11.2439 709/7f3eebc93780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:967 ]: Passenger core shutdown finished
2016/12/12 17:16:12 [info] 782#782: Using 32768KiB of shared memory for push module in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:71
[ 2016-12-12 17:16:12.2742 791/7fb0c37a0780 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1291 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ 2016-12-12 17:16:12.2820 794/7fe4d238b780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:982 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ 2016-12-12 17:16:12.2820 794/7fe4d238b780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:235 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ 2016-12-12 17:16:12.2832 794/7fe4d238b780 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:732 ]: Passenger core online, PID 794
[ 2016-12-12 17:16:12.2911 799/7f06bb50a780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:529 ]: Starting Passenger UstRouter...
[ 2016-12-12 17:16:12.2916 799/7f06bb50a780 age/Ust/UstRouterMain.cpp:342 ]: Passenger UstRouter online, PID 799
```

Anyway, it doesn't looks like an error, but a usual log.

UPDATE 2:
Nginx is running:

```
root       810     1  0 17:16 ?        00:00:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data   815   810  0 17:16 ?        00:00:00 nginx: worker process
ubuntu     853 32300  0 17:44 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto nginx
```

And when I try do curl localhost, it returns the HTML as expected!

UPDATE3:

When I run `systemctl status nginx`, I get the following error:

```
Dec 12 17:54:48 ip-172-31-40-156 systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
```

Trying to figure out what it is

UPDATE4:
Ran the command `nmap 35.160.22.104 -Pn PORT STATE SERVICE 22/tcp`and got the output:

```
Starting Nmap 7.01 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-12-12 18:05 UTC
Failed to resolve "PORT".
Failed to resolve "STATE".
Failed to resolve "SERVICE".
Unable to split netmask from target expression: "22/tcp"
Nmap scan report for ec2-35-160-22-104.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (35.160.22.104)
Host is up (0.0015s latency).
Not shown: 999 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

UPDATE5:

Output for `netstat -tuanp | grep 80`:

```
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: Blank page is really a white page? without any letters? ^^ Check nginx error logs. Confirm that you have a security group with port 80 open associated to that instance.. Give more details!

Comment: @Tomahock Exactly. It try to load for a while and then stops. No error, no message. I updated the question so maybe it helps to understand it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not a passenger guy, but confirm that nginx is running `$ ps -ef | grep nginx` Check in the server if it responds `$ curl localhost`. Did you confirm if you have a security group with the right ports opened?

Comment: @Tomahock updated the question again with the outputs... about that security group, I don't understand too much about it. How do I check that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your ec2 instance have a security group associated. 
You should go to AWS console EC2 -> Instances -> Click on your instance -> On the bottom 'Description' -> Security Group. Click on the name and you will be redirect to EC2-> Network and Security. Click on 'Edit inbound rules'  Add a rule:

- Type: HTTP

Save. And that should be fine!

Comment: If you are going to use HTTPs (and you should) add another rule to HTTPs as type that AWS also provider a pre made rule!

Comment: Oh, I did that when I launched the instance... but found something else on nginx and updated the question. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Try to run that command with sudo. If nginx is running (you could curl localhost) it really looks closed port: ```nmap 35.160.22.104 -Pn

PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 13.19 seconds``` If you try on the server `$ curl 35.160.22.104` it's going to fail right?

Comment: I updated the question with the output error for the nmap command. For the curl, it only works with localhost. Fot the public IP, it keeps executing and doesn't return anything... like the web browser

Comment: The nmap command was only `$ nmap 35.160.22.104 -Pn` but it just shows that your 80 port isn't open. Let's check if you have the port open on the server. try this: `$ netstat -tuanp | grep 80` . you should get something  like 0.0.0.0:80 LISTEN PID/nginx

Comment: it showed two lines but looks weird. Updated on question!

Comment: It looks fine. You should run this commands with sudo. Byt any way i stick to my opinion that it's the security group not properly configured.

Comment: The problem was the security group. I added HTTP as long as SSH for it when created, but for some reason it faded away. Sorry for extending the problem and thank you so much for your help! Saved my life =)